# Error while exporting geometry to CSV with MMQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, geometry, export, csv, mmqgis

I am importing a DIVA-GIS shapefile into QGIS. It has a lot of polygons on it. My aim is to group different groups of polygons together and dissolve their internal boundaries so that I end up with some larger polygons of amalgamated smaller ones. My understanding was that this is what the QGIS `Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to Singlepart` tool was for.

I have run this several times on the relevant polygons. It seems to run OK.

Then I go to `MMQGIS > Export Geometry to CSV` (the idea being to use the lat / long data in Tableau to create more map detail). This command has worked for me with the same DIVA-GIS data (just not a file that had had the Multipart to Single part command run on it).

I am getting the error below every time. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong / how / whether I can fix it?

```py
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorFileWriter' object has no attribute 'writerow' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Matt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 1594, in run
    attribute_file_name, field_delimiter, line_terminator, self.mmqgis_status_callback)
  File "C:/Users/Matt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_library.py", line 3145, in mmqgis_geometry_export_to_csv
    node_file.writerow(row)
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorFileWriter' object has no attribute 'writerow'

Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.10.0-A CoruÃ±a A CoruÃ±a, 6c816b4204 
Python Path:
•   C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python
•   C:/Users/Matt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
•   C:/Users/Matt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
•   C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
•   C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python37.zip
•   C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\DLLs
•   C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib
•   C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
•   C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37
•   C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
•   C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
•   C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
•   C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
•   C:/Users/Matt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use mmqgis? What happens if you use the qgis builtin csv export (e.g. with geom as wkt set)?

Comment: Thank you. I have the same problem. Can you please be more descriptive on how to execute the steps to edit the mmqgis_library.py.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like there is a typo in mmqgis version=2019.8.11.

In mmqgis_library.py replace line 3145

```
node_file.writerow(row)
```

with

```
node_file.writeRow(row).
```